USGS slope less than 30° excluding water bodies (Earth Engine)
My goal is to get the land with less than 30deg of slope and exclude water bodies. The USGS/3DEP/10m dataset in Earth Engine produces a slope of 0 for water bodies (e.g. lakes, or ponds). I'm curious if I'm going to be removing other valid land areas that happen to have 0 elevation.
def get_ideal_slope_from_elevation_image(elevation_image):
    slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation_image)
    mask = elevation_image.gt(0)  # remove 0 elevation values

    slope_30_or_less = slope.updateMask(mask)

    # Create a constant image of 1s
    constant_image = ee.Image(1)

    # Apply the slope mask to the constant image
    binary_slope = constant_image.updateMask(slope_30_or_less.gt(0).And(slope.lte(30)))

    return binary_slope

Does this code make sense? Does anyone have a better idea?

With that script, you will remove land areas with slope = 0. An alternative might be to use a water bodies product to mask them (e.g., https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_4_GlobalSurfaceWater)

Theres a lot of land with slope = 0 at 10m.  If you don't want water, you need to use some other dataset for determining water/not-water.
